# how to update UI before UIView animation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, animation, uiview

I add an animation to UIView in my program. There are many controls in the view. I tried to hide some controls before animation, so I set hidden property to YES. But it didn't work.It still visible on the layer during the animation.

here is some code:

```
button.hidden = YES;
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0f];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown forView:self.view cache:YES];
[UIView commitAnimations]
```

Could any one tell me how to hide controls before animation?
Or how to update control statues(control position, visible, etc)

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to animate a view, the statement that sets its new value, like (`button.hidden = YES`), should be located INSIDE your animation block, like so.

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0f];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown forView:self.view cache:YES];
button.hidden = YES;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: sorry,I didn't try to change the statement of button during animation,I try to change the statement before animation. When animation start, I wish the button is already invisible,thanks